# Can you start another application's services?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

In Android you can use an intent (explicit / implicit) to start another activity. Can the same be done for services? If so links to coded examples and reasons to do so would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If they're exported, yes.  If they aren't, no.  YOu'd do it the same way you would for a service in your own apk-  create an intent and call startService.

Comment: Can you think of any real life examples of needing to start a service from another app?

Comment: A company puts out several APKs that all use a common service to do background work.  That's a moderately common one.  Google Play Services is another-  a service as a library.